# Can't get transit directions in Japan

Tags: google-maps

Searching for directions from **35.443708,139.638026**
to **35.689487,139.691706**
yields results on [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=35.443708,139.638026&daddr=35.689487,139.691706&hl=en&sll=35.56736,139.66452&sspn=0.293232,0.54451&geocode=FfzTHAIdCrVSCA;FQ-UIAIduoZTCA&ttype=dep&date=10/15/12&time=11:54pm&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=ls&t=m&z=11&start=0), however this query to the directions API does not:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=true&departure_time=1350456190&destination=35.689487,139.691706&origin=35.443708,139.638026&mode=transit

Anyone have any ideas? It seems to be specific to Japan. You'll want to update the departure_time above to now if you're actually testing this.

I've filed this bug with Google, I'd rather find out it's something wrong with my query though: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4498

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you look at [**this spreadsheet**](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html), you can see that driving, (and transit), directions are not available for Japan through the API.

Comment: Driving directions are working now, but unfortunately transit directions are still not available. The Google Maps API page says that transit directions are experimental, so it may be a while before they have them for Japan.

Comment: A little while indeed, since 8 years later it's still not available.

Comment: The spreadsheet is gone (and [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20121022062631/https://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html) doesn't allow viewing it.)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed : according to https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#transit_directions_countries
it's not available ...

Answer (score 1):

Just an update, we investigated this recently and until now(Feb2015), it seems only driving and walking are available in japan using directions api

transit not available according to [maps faq](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#transit_directions_countries)

biking not available according to [maps coverage](https://developers.google.com/maps/coverage)

I also tried using javascript Directions service. Travel modes TRANSIT and  BIKING still does not work